# update using count from another table

Tags: sql, count

I want update wage in the staff table based on the staff members who have rented the most cars

```
UPDATE staff 
SET wage = wage + 5000 

WHERE COUNT(staffid) >= ALL
Select COUNT(staffid) FROM carforrent)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update s set
    s.wage = s.wage + 5000 
from staff s
join (
    select staffid
    from carforrent
    group by staffid
    having count(*) = (
        select top 1 count(*)
        from carforrent
        group by staffid
        order by count(*) desc
    )
) sq on sq.staffid=s.staffid
```

The innermost query finds the highest number of cars rented by any member of staff.  This number is used in a `having` - to identify all the members of staff that rented that number of cars.  That query is then `join`ed back onto the staff table to filter just the staff with a burning desire to rent cars - so that the `update` only gives them a pay rise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the database you are using, but you want something like this:

```
update staff
    set wage = wage + 5000
    where staffid in (select top 1 staffid
                      from carforrent
                      group by staffid
                      order by count(*) desc
                     );
```

This is SQL Server syntax, but similar constructs work in most databases.

Comment: that only gets one member of staff...  if 2 or more people have all rented the same amount of cars, the question implies they all get a pay rise...

Comment: Wont this only work for one staff member? If the highest number of cars for rent is 5 and they are two staff members with 5 then I need 5000 to be added to both their wages

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte
as
(
    select top 1 count(1) maxcount
    from carforrent
    group by staffid
    order by count(1) desc
)
update staff
set wage = wage + 5000
where staffid in(
    select staffid
    from carforrent
    group by staffid
    having count(1) = (select maxcount from cte)
);
```

I did not test it, hope it helps.

Good luck.